# Firebaes CNAME brought down website?

Tags: cname-record

I am adding firebase authentication to a website, it was working well so I decided to get the domain verified to add some more functionality.

On the firebase documentation, it says you need to add two CNAME and two TXT records to the domain, I did that but it didn't work the first time around and it also brought the website down, it seems as though the records weren't fully propagated.  I got in touch with Firebase and they said to try again, once they were fully propagated I got the green tick on Firebase but the next morning the website went down again.

What could be the cause of the website going down?

here is the CNAME & TXT records that brought the website down
[image]

Here is a screenshot of the records currently registered (minus the records above which had to be removed)
[image]

Here is a text file with the DNS records: [image]

Comment: What do the other records look like? Were you relying on a wildcard record which used to match those names until you started adding more specific records?

Comment: Well, it's effectively impossible to read your screenshot, so I'll let you judge if that is the problem. Personally I suspect that is it.

Comment: Well, it's not that I can't see or open the image, it's that the text is effectively gone. Sorry, but this is pointless.

Comment: @Aindriú If you want people to assist, please stop censoring the website's domain. It's very difficult to diagnose DNS stuff without the real address.

Comment: Thos two CNAME and TXT records will not bring your website down - not from the DNS POV.

Comment: Well they did and had to be removed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My impression from the question is that for your domain `example.com` (whatever it is), what you refer to is the web site no longer working specifically means that you can no longer navigate to `www.example.com` in a browser as this name no longer has address records.

You have a wildcard `*.example.com` `A`, which covers any non-existent names, but as you describe in your question, you added records for the names `www.example.com` (`TXT`) as well as `firebase1._domainkey.www.example.com` (`CNAME`).
The side-effect here is that when you add these records, the name `www.example.com` now actually exists, hence the wildcard no longer applies here!

If you are going to add these other records while still having address records at `www.example.com`, you will need to add address records at `www.example.com` specifically (side by side with the `TXT`).